# How to read the .xml file path in Eclipse rcp application using java?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have find the solution.This solution will help me to read file from appropriate folder path.
**

> String resourceFolder=""; URL url=new
>   URL("platform:/plugin/com.example"+resourceFolder);
>             String resourceFolderPath=org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getPath();
>             resourceFile=resourceFolderPath+"xxxx.xml";

**

Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: If it's in your Bundle, wouldn't you just be able to read it as a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileLocator` is the correct API to use to access plugin resources.

Use `FileLocator.find` to get a URL to a resource:

```java
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path("relative path in plugin"), null);
```

`bundle` is the `Bundle` for the plugin. For the current plugin you can get this using:

```java
Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(getClass());
```

to get the bundle of a different plugin use:

```java
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
```

The URL returned by `find` is an `bundleentry` URL. You can use `openStream` on this to read to resource.

If you want a `file` URL you can convert the url using:

```java
URL fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
```

This may cause Eclipse to copy the resource in to a file in a temporary location.